# Unity3d, referencing a separate script folder?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity 4+, is there a way of specifying a path to a folder outside of your project containing scripts that should be included in the build?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not in the Editor but if you're using Windows you can create a symbolic folder link and Unity Editor will correctly follow.  Here is a [better tutorial on symlinks](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/) than I can fit in an SO answer.

Basically you would do the following:

- Open a command shell as an Administrator
- Change folders to assets folder, for example: C:\Path\ToYour\Unity\Assets
- Create a link using mklink.  So for example, say you have a folder at C:\OtherFolder, you would use the following command:

> mklink /J other_folder C:\OtherFolder

That will create a symbolic link at C:\Path\ToYour\Unity\Assets\other_folder  that will point to C:\OtherFolder but it will show up in the Editor and will compile when you build your assets.

Make sure to include the `/J` option to create a hard folder link or mklink will just create a shortcut and I'm not sure that works.

Comment: Thanks, I havn't tried it out but I'll take your word for it :).

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

No that's not possible. `Unity3D` manage the project files `.csproj` autonomously. The scripts that will be compiled must be placed under `Assets/` folder.